# Jenkins pipeline groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Below is my simple jenkins pipeline groovy script by which it will create a pipeline with these 2 stages and the jobs we want to build,I want the job names in that for build and code analysis should get updated in the script under job configuration everytime by taking the data from the UI where the user will just provide the build jobname and code analysis jobname using Eclipse -

jenkinsfile script :-

```
stage('Build'){

    build job: 'job1'

}

stage('Code_Analysis'){

    build job: 'job2'

}
```

[image: Jenkins --> New item -->Pipeline job image]

[image: jenkins pipeline Job's script image]

Comment: your question is far from being clear

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Then please vote for close.

Comment: @OlegBogdanov I have an UI where the user will provide the jobnames (which are already there in jenkins) to build it as like under pipeline view.I want that jobnames should get updated into the job configuration of the pipeline script inside the  'pipeline job'.I have used string parameters to pass values to the script,but i want to know how to use the string parameters in .groovy script file to edit the text. Pls find the image attached .

Answer (score 0):

While your question is a bit vague, I guess the problem is that your Jenkinsfile does not include the node statement:

```
node {
    stage('Build'){
        build job: 'job1'
    }

    stage('Code_Analysis'){
        build job: 'job2'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to pass job name as parameters. You can use string parameter e.g. JOB1 & JOB2. Then pass that to build job as it is. No need of curly braces or inverted commas like shown below-

```
stage('Build'){
    build job: JOB1
}
stage('Code_Analysis'){
    build job: JOB2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the job name can be utilised using ${name} variable in jenkins pipeline